# Android Intent opening wrong class

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a menu with this code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String classes[] = {"Add a fight to the card", "Add a fighter", "Edit a fighter"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    switch (position){
        case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddFight.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        case 1:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddFighter.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
    }
```

When I click on `case 0:` in my list, the intent in `case 1:` is opened instead of `case 0:`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to insert a `break` statement in your switch cases, otherwise, as written, your code will perform `case 0` then immediately perform `case 1` as well.

```
switch (position)
{ 
    case 0:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddFight.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    case 1:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddFighter.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
        break;
}
```

Note: Strictly speaking, you don't need the `break` in `case 1`. However, it is good practice to do so. Also, this will prevent "fall through" should you add additional `case` statements later.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will launch the activities back to back. Insert break for case statement then it will work. Last case statement does not need to have break statement.

```
switch (position){
        case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddFight.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        case 1:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddFighter.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
    }
```